# How to set Signature size in java (bouncycastle)?

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle, signature

Are there any way to set the signature size while making DER file using bouncycastle.

Now I am making cert file using org.bouncycastle.
The following is my code. It works fine, but I could not handle the signature length.

** for the SHA256WITHRSA signature algorithm, the length is static as 256 for 2048 RSA key, and 128 for 1024 RSA key.**

*I want to make a cert with 2048 public key and 128 signature.*

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
KeyPair keyPair = createKeyPair();

JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(new X500Name("CN=Issuer"), BigInteger.ONE, new GregorianCalendar().getTime(), new GregorianCalendar().getTime(), new X500Name("CN=Subject"), keyPair.getPublic());
            
JcaContentSignerBuilder signerBuiler = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WITHRSA").setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
ContentSigner contentSigner = signerBuiler.build(keyPair.getPrivate());
X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).getCertificate(certBuilder.build(contentSigner));

certificate.verify(keyPair.getPublic());
System.out.println( certificate);
```

As the following, it has 2048 public key, but the signature size is 128 byte. This is DER file what I wanna make.
[image]

Comment: To achieve this, the public key in the certificate would have to be 2048 bits and the signing (private) key 1024 bits. So it is possible, but not for a self-signed certificate that is generated by your code (where the public and private keys belong together and thus have the same size).

Comment: Good news! You could randomize the signature, say using RSA-PSS, and then try and compute about 2\*\*1024 randomized signatures. You'd expect about one of these to be <= 128 bytes. However, bad news! You could never finish this in the lifetime of the universe, and your adversaries could factor your modulus and forge your signatures long before you'd gotten your 128-byte result. Math giveth and math taketh away.

Comment: That certificate is *signed* with a 1024-bit RSA key. It isn't self-signed, it's signed with the key of the issuer. It would be considered insecure by modern standards and most browsers would show some kind of warning.

Comment: You have got a different issuer and subject, so by definition it is not a self signed certificate. If you create a separate keypair for the subject (2048 bits) & issuer (1024 bits) and use the public key of the subject and the private key of the issuer then you've fulfilled your request. Of course, that means that the issuer would have a shorter key than the issuer, and that's exactly the wrong way around. Generally the certificates of the issuer are valid for longer and as they can sign multiple certs, the key should be stronger not shorter/weaker.

Answer (score 2):

The output of RSA operations is always the size of the RSA key used. 2048 bits is 256 bytes. It's impossible to get a 128-byte result using a 256-byte key.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but it is possible, I have a demo DER file what I wanna make. It has 2048 RSA key and 128 signature length.

Comment: @Dong0321 No, it's not possible to get a 128-byte signature with a 2048-bit key. What you are describing is the signed content being a 2048-bit key. That's no problem; you can sign any data, of any length. It could be a shopping list, a photo of your toe, or another public key. But the resulting RSA signature will be the size of the signing key. So if you want a 128-byte signature, you *must* sign with a 1024-bit key (which is not recommended from a security perspective).

Comment: then... is it possible to make RSA key pair with 1024 private key and 2048 public key?

Comment: @Dong0321: Yes, but not really, it's the size of the modulus (public key) that counts here. You need to use elliptic curves, not RSA, if you want shorter signatures.